# Django-CMS FilerImageField: Validator function

Tags: django-cms, django-filer

I'm trying to write a validator for a Django-CMS `FilerImageField`. The following validator function is used for a default `ImageField`. When I copy it to the new Model, it will crash with the message `'int' object has no attribute 'file'`. Obviously a different type of value is being passed to the validator function. I can't seem to find information on what kind of data is being passed to the validator. How do I correctly reference the file so I can `get_image_dimensions()`?

```
def validate(fieldfile_obj):
    width, height = get_image_dimensions(fieldfile_obj.file) #crash
    if width > 1000:
        raise ValidationError("This is wrong!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found it. `fieldfile_obj` in this case contains the primary key of a Image record. The solution was to get an instance of `filer.models.Image` and pass this instance's `file` property to the validator function:

```
from filer.models import Image

# ... code ...

def validate(fieldfile_obj):
    image = Image.objects.get(pk=fieldfile_obj)
    width, height = get_image_dimensions(image.file)
    if width > 1000:
        raise ValidationError("This is wrong!")
```